# Como alterar o ícone de um arquivo .jar?

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber como faço pra mudar o ícone de um arquivo .jar.
Há alguma maneira de se fazer isso usando o Scene Builder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu não acredito que você consiga mudar o ícone do arquivo .jar, já que quem define isso é o próprio SO (você pode até mudar o ícone sem utilizar java, mas isso mudaria para todo .jar que existe no computador). O que eu já fiz é mudar o ícone que fica na barra de tarefas e na janela do programa quando ele é executado usando algo parecido com isso (não tenho o código comigo agora, mas é algo bem parecido):

```
getFrame().setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("caminhoDaImagem"));
```

O que eu já vi algumas pessoas fazendo, é utilizar um executable wrapper pra "transformar" (ele não transforma o .jar em .exe, mas não vou entrar em detalhes) o .jar em um executável. Algumas ferramentas pra isso são:

[launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)
[Jsmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)